# Angular: Component Iteration: Calls method in wrong component instance

Tags: angular

I have a very weird issue.
I have the following iteration in my template:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-group-selector
        (selectedValuesChanged)="updateSelectedGroups(group.name, $event)"
        *ngFor="let group of groups"
        [allValues]="group.allValues"
        [selectedValues]="group.selectedValues"
        class="chart-control-groups-item"
        label="{{ group.name }}"
    ></app-group-selector>
</div>
```

inside `app-group-selector` I have this template:

```html
<div class="result-area" [hidden]="!isResultSelectionListOpen">
    <div class="select-all-selector">
        <app-checkbox [inputId]="'select-all'" [(ngModel)]="selectAllItemsCheckbox" [compact]="true" (change)="handleSelectAllCheckbox()"></app-checkbox>
            <label [for]="'select-all'" class="result-label">Select All</label>
        </div>
        <ul class="result-selection-list">
            <li *ngFor="let item of allSelectionItems" class="result-item">
                <app-checkbox [inputId]="item.key" [compact]="true" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" (change)="handleCheckItem()"></app-checkbox>
                <label [for]="item.key" class="result-label">{{ item.key }}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and in the `.ts` file I have the method:

```js
handleSelectAllCheckbox(): void {
    console.log('all items: ' + this.allSelectionItems);
}
```

Now, in the UI I have 3 `app-group-selector` components. The strange thing is, that, when I click on the "Select All" checkbox of the **last** component, it triggers the `handleSelectAllCheckbox()` method of the **first** component (I can see that because the console.log shows me the wrong `allSelectionItems` list.

Now, there should be **no connection at all** between these components - they should live for their own.

The component is declared in the `app.module` declarations array as usual.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[inputId]="'select-all'"` is the culprit here.
On iteration there will be multiple elements with same `id` in one **document**, all the `for="select-all"` will always refer the first element with that id.

Now you know the solution, you'll have to use dynamic values for `id` and `for` like you have done below `[inputId]="item.key"` and `[for]="item.key"`.

Comment: Oh man, yes, you're so right. Thanks a lot. I really struggled to see that somehow :)